# My mercedes 2012 not crank ( don’t start engine )

Tags: starting, mercedes-benz

My mercedes 2012 if i leave it for 30 minute and when i try to start the engine, it not start and bettery is okay and dashboard lights are okay and head lights are okay. So what is the problem?!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! When you say "won't start", what do you mean? You turn the key and you get nothing (no noise from the starter)? What do you have to do to get it started again? Which model/engine of MB do you have?

Comment: How do you confirm battery is OK? Are you load testing it, using a voltmeter or ?